# How to find the webpages linking to a pdf?

Tags: google-search, search-engine

I found an interesting PDF with my last Google research, via a direct link to it ( Google result was like "http://example.com/somefolder/interesting.pdf").

I would like to put the pdf in context, that is to say find a webpage linking to it. How can I find it? I tried to google  http://example.com/somefolder/interesting.pdf, but I got only one result (of course the pdf itself). If I google "example.com/somefolder/interesting.pdf" I get no result.

Does that mean that the original pdf is an "orphan" attachment?

Is there any option in advanced search that I missed? 
Maybe is there another search engine with this feature?

Comment: type `filetype:pdf` + `website name` in the google search box

Comment: @Shakehar No. This will not show the sites linking to specific file but it will show sites hosting specific file. This is not what OP wants.

Comment: @mnmnc I guess I misread the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has a special HowTo page for you [here](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=adv_sitespecific&answer=1734233) where you will find advice how to search for a specific link - just as you've described.

> Use the "**link**:" operator.
>
> For example, to find pages that link to www.google.com, use [
>   link:google.com ]. You can also search for links to specific pages
>   like [ link:google.com/images ].

Comment: thank you! the option is no more available in http://www.google.com/advanced_search , but I am glad the function is still there! By the way, unfortunately my interesting.pdf seems to be orphan, or linked by a non-indexed page

Comment: As user @BettySammy notes below, it looks like the link operator is dead in 2017: https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/#find-competitor-links